# Spring 4 WebSockets + SockJS - websocket:handshake-interceptors never invoked

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs

I am testing Spring 4's different WebSocket approaches.

The most basic, works well, invoking the interceptor (I want to publish the HttpSession attributes):

```
<websocket:handlers>
    <websocket:mapping path="/simpleChatHandler" handler="simpleChatHandler"/>
    <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
    </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
</websocket:handlers>
```

Here is when the interceptor is invoked in `org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest()`:

```
[...]
try {
    Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (!chain.applyBeforeHandshake(request, response, attributes)) {
```

However when I use the SockJS handler, the interceptor is never called:

```
<websocket:handlers>
    <websocket:mapping path="/simpleChatHandlerSockJS" handler="simpleChatHandler"/>
    <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
    </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
    <websocket:sockjs/>
</websocket:handlers>
```

It seems that `org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler`, unlike `WebSocketHttpRequestHandler`, doesn't have a "interceptors" attribute.

Is this a Spring bug? Do you know any way to publish HttpSessionAttributes to SockJS websockets?

Answer (score 2):

Edited: 28 April, 2014:

Ok, what I have been doing is configuring Websockets through Java, as I found out that its more flexible:

Try this code as part of Java configuration:

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addHandler(new Handler(), "/endpoint")
    .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptors())
  .withSockJS();
}
```

I am using this code and its working for me. You would need to reference the spring-websocket documentation for the complete code.

Cheers

Comment: You can't define the sockjs element there (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException), the schema doesn't allow it. I think that the interceptor support isn't really implemented when using sockjs...